# Jetpack compose TopAppBar gives a call error

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I get an error when I write the following in Jetpack compose TopAppBar.
I think it's a rudimentary mistake, but I don't know.
[write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcj5J.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzF2l.png)

```
TopAppBar( // ← error:None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
    title = Text(text = "hogrhoge"),
    actions = {IconButton(...)}
```

Comment: I changed it according to the answer. and Updated androidx.activity:activity-compose  to 1.4.0. Then it worked.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the Scaffold function definition

```
fun Scaffold(
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  toastHostState: ToastHostState = remember { ToastHostState() },
  toastHost: @Composable (ToastHostState) -> Unit = { ToastHost(it) },
  statusBarMode: StatusBarMode = StatusBarMode.Red,
  topBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {}, // it's expecting a lambda
  bottomBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
  floatingActionButton: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
  backgroundColor: Color = NicolletTheme.colors2.backgroundPrimary,
  contentColor: Color = NicolletTheme.colors2.textPrimary,
  content: @Composable (PaddingValues) -> Unit
)
```

It's expecting a lambda, you need to wrap it inside a `{}`

```
TopAppBar(
  title  = { Text(title = "aa") //your composable } 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter `title` is of type `@Composable () -> Unit`, which means you have to pass composable function there. You are instead passing value returned from `Text` function, which is `Unit`. And it's the same with `actions` parameter. What you should do is this:

```
TopAppBar(
    title = { Text(...) },
    actions = { IconButton(...) },
    ...
)
```